# mongodb simple query speed if index much bigger then available RAM

Tags: mongodb

I have a very simple data structure. Let's assume that documents in collection will looks like this:

```
{
 _id: "...",
 indexedField: "value 1",
 ...
}
```

`indexedField` data will be indexed.

The problem for me is that amount of that document will be really huge. Let's think like 1 billion. But the machine who will handle that db do not have a lot of memory, maybe like 4Gb, not more.

most of the queries I need to be run looks like this:

```
db.collection.find({indexedField: "queryValue"}).skip(offset).limit(100)
```

So the question is - will it perform well or will demonstrate poor performance because of memory swapping.

Comment: How many documents are there for any given value of `indexedField`?

Comment: Could you give us a hint by typing `db.collection.find({indexedField: "queryValue"}).skip(offset).limit(100).explain()`

Comment: @Thilo Potentially really a lot. Sometimes it could be 10, sometimes could be 50 millions.

Comment: It's going to be based on the working set. **You need to try it.** It's likely to perform very poorly. But, it's based on usage patterns. If you only do a few queries a minute, it won't matter much. More than likely you'll have a very underpowered database that will only get faster by adding the proper amount of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

That would depend on two factors:

1. The data field being indexed, if the data field is integers, the index size would not be much, and you shall be fine. You can do one more optimization by overwriting mongodb "_id" with integer based keys if they are unique ( keeping in mind autosharding and future scaling though ).
2. `db.collection.find({indexedField: "queryValue"}).skip(offset).limit(100)`

This query is expensive, and keeps on getting slow as you increase the offset, since mongodb will fetch full records, and then do a scanning to skip and provided LIMIT N documents.
So,if a large number of documents match "queryValue" and offset is high, the query will be slow.

Comment: If, for example, each number was store as a 4 byte integer, and all values were unique, you'd have an index that exceeded 4gb in size. That won't perform well in the specified system.